# Ссылку авторства разрешено указывать на фото используемые в приложение Appstore?

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c, дизайн

Автор фото дает согласие на размещение только при условие указание ссылок на него,
пропустит ли appstore?

Comment: Избегайте только таких фоток в скриншотах, с этим часто проблемы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А почему нет-то? Вот как раз за несоблюдение авторского права приложение и могут удалить)

Answer (score 1):

Стандартной практикой является указывание ссылки на автора (или его копирайт) в информации о приложении или в отдельном дисклеймере.

За это никто удалять не будет.

Comment: спасибо так и сделаю